# Elasticsearch Pagination with timestamp range

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

[Elasticsearch official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination) introduce that elasticsearch can realize pagination by composite aggregations.

The composite aggregation will fetch data many times to get all results.

So my question is, Can I use range from `now-1h` to `now` when I execute composite aggregation?

If I can. How to composite aggregation query keep source data unchanging when every range query have different `now`.

If I can't. My query below has no error and the result seems to be right.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user_device": {
      "composite": {
        "after": {
          "user_name": "alen.lv"
        },
        "size": 100,
        "sources": [
          {
            "user_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "user_name"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user_mac": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_mac",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would highly encourage you not to use `now` and instead pass a precomputed date at the application level. And keep on using the same value when you paginate. This will solve your issue with `now` and having a precomputed date, will make use of Elasticsearch request cache.

Comment: Additionally, if this is feasible for your application, you might want to round your date down to minutes to improve ES cache hit ratio.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas thanks. Your said makes much sense.